# Python, replicate rows in a data frame by a column's integer and decrease it accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and I would like to replicate all the rows that are over one in one of the columns and for item replicated, decrease the amount in that column by one.
the data frame:

```
            Item  Weight  Bags    Must  quantity  must quantity  bags column  length assigned bag
0     planes bag    8.50  planes   v       1              1          6                None
1  Full Bandolera   3.76  planes   v       3              2          6                None
2  tail             0.30  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
3  central wing     1.08  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
4  engine           0.44  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
5  height steer     0.12  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
6  dihedral         0.40  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None   
7  pods bag         8.72  pods     v       1              1          4                None
8  Pod              1.74  pods     v       3              2          4                None
9  optic            0.86  pods     v       2              2          4                None
10 thermal          1.20  pods     v       3              2          4                None
```

would become:

```
            Item  Weight  Bags    Must  quantity  must quantity  bags column  length assigned bag
0     planes bag    8.50  planes   v       1              1          6                None
1  Full Bandolera   3.76  planes   v       1              2          6                None
2  Full Bandolera   3.76  planes   v       1              2          6                None
3  Full Bandolera   3.76  planes   v       1              2          6                None
4  tail             0.30  planes  <NA>     1              2          6                None
5  tail             0.30  planes  <NA>     1              2          6                None
6  tail             0.30  planes  <NA>     1              2          6                None

# and so on
```

So far, I got this code, which raises no errors but doesn't affect the data frame at all.

```py
    def multiply_row():
        for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            while row['quantity'] > 1:
                (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.quantity)]
                 .assign(quantity=1))
                return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here looping by each row is not necessary, solution is simplify, because if `quantity` is `1` after repeat it return same row:

```
def multiply_row(df)
    return df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.quantity)].assign(quantity=1).reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = multiply_row(df)
```